# Study of behaviour of this system of ODE's .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

I am having a system of differential equations as follows, now this is a non-linear system -

$\dot{x}(t) = -0.28571(x + f_{1}) + 0.00057(g_{1} - z) $

$\dot{y}(t) = \frac{1}{c_{2}}(-2.4*y + 0.000101*f_{1}*y + 2.4*g_{2} -c_{2}*\dot{h_{1}} - 0.000101*h_{1}*x - 0.006*x)$

$\dot{z}(t) = -\dot{g_{1}} - \frac{f_{1}}{c_{1}}(0.0000113*g_{1} + 0.0072) - \frac{z}{c_{1}}(-0.0000113*x + 2.4) - \frac{f_{1}.z}{c_{1}}(0.0000741) + \frac{y}{c_{1}}(2.4) + 19.6*c_{3} + \frac{1}{c_{1}}(2.4*h_{1} - 2.4*g_{1} + 0.0000741*g_{1}*x + 0.0072*x)$.

Where $f_{1},g_{1},g_{2},h_{1}$ are continuous functions of time $t$ ,$c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}$ are the constants .

Now I am interested in the functions $f_{1},g_{1},g_{2},h_{1}$ and constants $c_{1},c_{2},c_{3}$ so that chaotic dynamics may occur , like I had selected these values 
Initial values - $x(0) = -10000 , y(0) = 100 , z(0) = 4 , c_{1} = 10 ,c_{2} = 10 , c_{3} = 101$,
Due to physical constraint $x$ has to take negative values.

I got the phase space as something like this - 
[image]

Actally I am interested to explore this system with some interesting properties it might have, also it may appear little clumsy and sophisticated.

Also this doesnot appear to be chaotic , any speciality in this system of ODE one can observe and is Chaotic behaviour possible here?

Like any method we can use so as to study these system of Non linear ODE's so that we can extract dynamical behaviour from the system.

$EDIT$

$x(t)$ represents the initial velocity of the wind from ocean to land surface.

$f_{2}$ represents the velocity of the wind above the land surface which is usually zero but I am taking it as a function of time to generalize the phenomena.

$g_{1}(t)$ represents the initial temperature at the land-ocean interface.

$z(t)$ represents the temperature at the land surface.

$h_{1}$ is the initial moisture content at the land-ocean interface.

$y(t)$ represents the moisture content at the land surface.

$c_{1},c_{2},c_{4}$ are the constants

Actually I am mainly interested in the following -
Like which specific functions should I choose in order to get a Chaotic behaviour and does this system seem to generate some interesting dynamics like for a choice of functions and constants?

Any help is great!

Comment: How did you choose the functions $f_1$, $g_1$, $g_2$ and $h$ and how are they constrained? Also, why didn’t you look at a longer temporal evolution?

Comment: Unknown functions are bad. However, it looks like that your system has a form $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = A(t) \mathbf{x} + b(t)$, am I right?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft actually I did the same system of ODE's when I treated the $f_{i},g_{i},h_{i}$ as constants like say moisture content , temperature , Precipitation as a circulation model,next here I tried to make them as functions of time and see their dynamics which is much more realistic phenomena.I think only constraint on the functions is they must be continuous,does this help?also longer temporal evolution?does that mean behaviour as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Evgeny I think there are some $x.z $ terms in the equation.

Comment: @BAYMAX: *longer temporal evolution?does that mean behaviour as $t→∞$?* – No, just longer. Wait, until the dynamics either clearly escalates or assumes some stable or oscillatory behaviour. The phase-space plot you are showing could belong to all kinds of dynamics. Right now, there are too many unknowns. Also: What is your actual question? Please [edit] your question to specify.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft is the edit better?,perhaps if possible we can discuss in [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/differential-equations-difference-equations-dynamical-systems-chaos-theory-non) chat room

Comment: *is the edit better?* – Not really. I do not want to understand oceanography or meteorology to understand your question.

Comment: There is no short answer to your question. It's impossible to just look at equations in dimensions greater than 2 and say "oh, it's chaotic". The best that you can do is to start from really simple system (constant functions instead of arbitrary) and study what dynamics do you observe in that case. If you find chaotic dynamics in that simple case, you may try to make your functions periodic and check whether chaoticity preserves. But my opinion is that first you should answer yourself why do you want chaos in that example. Maybe I'm wrong, but it might be a bit artificial in this case. Or not)